# ModuleNotFoundError when tried to run my file

Tags: python

I've been building a simple CLI.

My `main.py` looks like this:

```
import prompt <- This is my file
import utils <- This too.

# blah blah blah
```

When I just ran `python3 main.py`, it works just fine. But after running `python3 setup.py install` and running `myCLI somecommand` on my terminal, I got this:

```
0.0.1-py3.9.egg/testCVRCLI/main.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt'
```

I checked whether it works by running `python3 main.py`, and it worked fine.

**EDIT**

```
# main.py

import prompt
import utils
import click

@click.group()
def main():
    pass

@main.command()
def setupdb():
    # some code

@main.command()
def create_data():
   # some code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if platform.system() != "Darwin":
        utils.print("This is currently only for Mac users.")
    else :
        main()
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
testCVRCLI
      |- setup.py
      |- CVRCLI_folder
           |- __init__.py
           |- main.py
           |- prompt.py
           |- utils.py
```

My `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Setting up
setup(
        name="myCLI", 
        version=VERSION,
        author="My Name",
        author_email="My Email",
        description=DESCRIPTION,
        long_description=LONG_DESCRIPTION,
        long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
        packages=find_packages(),
        install_requires=[
            "click",
            "mysql-connector-python",
            "protobuf",
            "six",
        ], 
        license="MIT",
        classifiers= [
            "Environment :: Console",
            "Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha",
        ],
        entry_points = """
            [console_scripts]
            myCLI=CVRCLI_folder.main:main
        """
)
```

Comment: What is `prompt`? Is it a module in your project (i.e. `prompt.py`) or a third party package? What does your `setup.py` look like?

Comment: It is my file i created.

Comment: Can you find it under `0.0.1-py3.9.egg/testCVRCLI/` directory?

Comment: If possible then share some more details of `main.py`

Comment: `0.0.1-py3.9.egg` is a file that looks like this: `6413 aacf caec 6deb 5a4f baf6 a949 b6f0`

Comment: I don't understand why, but there's not directory under `0.0.1-py3.9.egg`

Comment: Did you remember to package the files in `setup.py`? It seems you're messing up the packaging.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh What should I do in `setup.py`?

Comment: can you share a detailed directory structure with us?

Comment: @AgentNoby Normally you use `find_packages`, which handles everything, but there's more extensive configurations if you need [them](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html). You can manually specify paths as well. Maybe share your `setup.py`, which is more important than anything else here.

Comment: I beleive that because main.py is in your package, you should refer to the other modules it imports from the same package relative to the package root, i.e. `import .prompt` rather than `import prompt`

Comment: No. I can't do that. I got error doing it on VSCode

Comment: Either than or move main.py outside the package

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: I think it should be `import CVRCLI_folder.prompt` then, if you're running using F5 from vscode it'll set the working directory to be the root folder.

Comment: See this version https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/main/allennlp/__main__.py - in the `run()` command (similar to your `main()` )  they import `allennlp.commands` not `commands` or `.commands`

Comment: I did it but i still get the same error .

Comment: Does `import myCLI.prompt` work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236795/discussion-between-agent-noby-and-david-waterworth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this like this:

```
try:
    import utils
    import prompt
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from . import utils
    from . import prompt
```